# Returning a struct from a function

Tags: c, data-structures, logic

I have a function in which puts data into a struct. My struct looks like this:

```
 typedef struct vertex_tag{
    int visited;
    double weight;
    int prev;
 }vertex_t;
```

I initialize it like this;

```
vertex_t * vertex[G->vertices];
    for(i=0; i < G->vertices; i++)
    {
        vertex[i] = (vertex_t*)malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));
        vertex[i]->weight = FLT_MAX;
        vertex[i]->visited = 0;
    }
```

It goes through the function putting data into the array, weight, visited and prev.

My question is, how do I get those values in my main function? Would I create another

```
vertex * vertex[]
```

In my main then set it equal to what I return?

Any thoughts?

Comment: In C, don't cast the `malloc`. It's not necessary and you might hide a missing declaration warning if you forget to include stdlib.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Allocating on the heap:

You should use `malloc` to create your array. Otherwise, you create the array on the stack and you can't return it. If you return the address of your array, the data may be corrupted.

Replace:

```
vertex_t * vertex[G->vertices];
```

to

```
vertex_t ** vertex = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t*) * G->vertices);
```

And `return vertex` which is of type `vertex_t **`.

#### An array of `vertex_t` instead of an array of pointers:

Also, it is not the question but I'm wondering why are you using an array of pointers. You could change your code like that:

```
vertex_t * vertex = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t) * G->vertices);
for(i=0; i < G->vertices; i++)
{
    vertex[i].weight = FLT_MAX;
    vertex[i].visited = 0;
}
```

And `return vertex`, of type `vertex_t *` (an array of `vertex_t`). If you need the address of an element in that array, you can still do `&vertex[i]`.

Both approaches would work but in your solution, you do extra memory allocations which use more memory, it's slower and you'll need to free that memory at some point. At a hardware point of view, you'll also do more cache misses leading to a slower code if you frequently iterate over all the array.

The only usage would be if you have vertices created by another function and you don't want to copy the data in your array.

I'd suggest you to draw the 2 solutions: one is an array with big cells and the other is an array with pointers to individual cells.

Comment: Okay and when I return my function how do I get it in my main? Do I set it to another vertex_t?

Comment: `vertex_t ** vertex_in_main = my_function(with any args)`

Comment: Okay perfect! That will also keep my vertex[]->weight values as well correct?

Comment: Yes. But why are you using an array of `vertex_t *` and not directly an array of `vertex_t`?

Comment: You mean like vertex_t vertex instead of vertex_t * vertex?

Comment: Okay I see what you did. What are the advantages of that over what I did? For better understanding.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you very much. So if I do it the new way. I would just return vertex*?

Comment: Yes, you return a pointer to the first element of that array. An element is of type `vertex_t` so you return a `vertex_t*`.

Comment: Okay so in main I would do vertex_t * vertex_in_main(args). Then I could do something like, vertex[5].weight and get the correct weight?

Comment: You would do: `vertex_t *vertex = my_function(args);` and then you could do something like `vertex[5].weight`.

Comment: Okay perfect ill give it a try!

Comment: So my exact return statement would be: return vertex*;   ?

Comment: No. It would be `return vertex`.

Comment: Thats what I thought and I get this: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: Because you probably forgot to change the return type of your function. Make sure it's `vertex_t*`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `vertex` is an array, you can not return an array from a function. 
Either you have to...

```
1. return the pointer to the array from the function 
or
2. Put the `vertex` array in a structure and return the structure.
```

Comment: Returning the address of the array `vertex` which is allocated on the stack would be a problem. The array needs to be malloc'ed.